# Unable to filter rows in panda dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which the `name` column has a few values.

Using `Counter()` from `collections`:

```
Counter(df.name)
```

gives

```
Counter({'': 13460,
         'alpha': 986,
         'beta': 22480,
         'gamma': 123})
```

After doing this:

```
df['name'] = df.loc[df['name'] != '']['name'].apply(lambda x: x + '-suffix')
Counter(df.name)
```

I get:

```
Counter({nan: 13460,
         'alpha-suffix': 986,
         'beta-suffix': 22480,
         'gamma-suffix': 123})
```

How do I select all those rows without a null string?

Comment: I'm not sure what `Counter` has to do with the question. Have you tried `no_null_rows = df[~df['name'].isnan()]` ?

Comment: can you include sample data? other wise it is not easy to help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign back, because for non matched values get `NaN`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['','d','','d'], 'val': [10, 20,20,30]})
print(df)
  name  val
0        10
1    d   20
2        20
3    d   30

df['name'] = df.loc[df['name'] != '', 'name']
print(df)
  name  val
0  NaN   10
1    d   20
2  NaN   20
3    d   30

df['name'] = df.loc[df['name'] != '', 'name']
print(Counter(df.name))
Counter({nan: 2, 'd': 2})
```

---

```
s = df.loc[df['name'] != '', 'name']
print(Counter(s))
Counter({'d': 2})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['name'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: x + '-suffix' if x!='' else x)
```

You could apply the function to everyone with a condition. It will give you the right number of rows
That is if you want to keep the same Dataset. Else, you can still create a new one. You just can't use the same one with a different number of rows.

```
temp_df = df['name'] != '']
```